# How does Eclipse execute such a fast search for hits to a phrase/regexp

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, search

Eclipse searches across a large project for all matches to a phrase (even a regexp phrase) surprisingly fast.

Do they use `java.util.regex` internally?
I assume that they do not index with a search engine, because their searches are too slow for that, yet there is some delay the very first time you do a search after launching eclipse.

Comment: I think they do use some indexer whose indexes are stored in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core

Comment: But the indexer wouldn't fare too well with general regex search, which also seems quite fast in eclipse.

Comment: eclipse dramatically improved the performance of code lookup-related tasks like searching references, creating a type hierarchy and even code completion. This is due to a new design, inspired by nWire, which uses the h2 database engine as a persistent storage for this data.

Comment: @DinupKandel you should convert that comment to an answer and provide sources ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Eclipse Helios (3.6) includes an improved version of Eclipse PDT,
>   labeled 2.2. It is also included in the current Zend Studio (7.1 and
>   above). Among other enhancements, it dramatically improved the
>   performance of code lookup-related tasks like searching references,
>   creating a type hierarchy and even code completion. This is due to a
>   new design, inspired by nWire, which uses the h2 database engine as a
>   persistent storage for this data.
>
> The h2 database is a high-performance, low profile, Java native
>   database engine, created as a successor to the widely used HSQLDB. It
>   is open source and free to use. nWire uses h2 since its' early days.
>
> Source: http://www.nwiresoftware.com/blogs/nwire/2010/09/five-tips-speeding-eclipse-pdt-and-nwire

In short, it looks like you're seeing these improvements because Eclipse utilizes the [h2](/questions/tagged/h2) database engine.

Then, if you dig a little deeper, here's a [quick sampling if the H2 source code](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/tools/org/h2/jaqu/util/GenerateModels.java?r=4516); it does indeed look like they're leveraging `java.util.regex`:

```
20 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
21 import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```